# Why some sd cards are not detected at all?

Tags: usb, xubuntu, sd-card, card-reader

I have an Toshiba Qosmio F50-125 laptop and it have built in sd card reader, and i am running Xubuntu 16.04 and i have a problem some of sd cards are not detected at all, not even in Gparted. Actually i have totally of 4 sd cards.

```
pqi 256mb sd card
kingmax micro sd with adapter 4gb
apacer micro sd with adapter 4gb
and ScanDisk SDHC 4GB card
```

And the only one that is recognized is `ScanDisk` I use that card in my Nikon D3100 camera, the other cards are not recognized at all when i try to put them in sd card reader.
But when i am on windows they are recognized when i put them in sd card reader, also they are recognized when i use external usb card reader.

The laptop have led indicator when the card is in reader so when i put the card (any of them) i can see that led indicator flashes on laptop.

Comment: Does your Toshiba Qosmio F50-125 manual give any information regarding what cards it's compatible with?

Comment: It should be compatible with all the sd cards since i can read them while i am on windows, it looks like this is more of a linux problem.

Comment: Oh, are you dual-booting Windows on the same hardware? Sorry that wasn't clear in your question. Please add that info to your question along with the output of `lspci` Thank you for helping us help you!